# How to get Block using JsonRpc from eosjs using nodejs?

Tags: eosjs, javascript

Whenever I try to get the block using the eosjs in NodeJS like in the example I get the error 'Invalid Block number or ID, must be greater than 0 and less than 64 characters'

Altho when I use other fetch methods such as the fetch from nodeos, it works just fine:
https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get-block

I got the info on how to do this fetch from the eos documentation:
https://eosio.github.io/eosjs/latest/reading-blockchain-examples/#get-block

```
const { JsonRpc } = require('eosjs');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const rpc = new JsonRpc('https://api.eosnewyork.io/', { fetch });

async function main() {
  try {
    let info = await rpc.get_info();
    console.log(await rpc.get_block(info.last_irreversible_block_num));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
}
main();
```

Answer (score 0):

EOS New York disabled get_block API. Use another endpoint. You can find one from the next:

https://www.eosdocs.io/resources/apiendpoints/